# Array merging/manipulation with Velocity

Tags: velocity

I have an array set inside a velocity template that contains some paths.
The idea is to put a few "default" .js/.css files that 90% of the pages will use in this array.
However, the other pages will still have to be able to add/delete values from this array, in case there are no linked files at all, or I need to add some.

Given this code:

```
#set ( $head.scripts = [ "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js", "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.0/jquery-ui.min.js" ] )

#foreach ($URI in $head.scripts)
<script type="text/javascript" src="$URI"></script>
#end
```

Is there any way to add/delete values from these defaults?
I have seen this [list tool](https://velocity.apache.org/tools/1.4/javadoc/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/ListTool.html), but it looks like it's not enough for what I need.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If this array is created in Velocity then it is backed by ArrayList class, so it supports all corresponding methods.

```
$head.scripts.add("new element")
$head.scripts.remove(0)
```

Comment: Can you answer this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799618/list-in-velocity-macro-cannot-find-contains-method?

Answer (score 1):

I believe we can use any methods from [here](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse341/98au/java/jdk1.2beta4/docs/api/java/util/List.html), such as `add`, `addAll`, `remove` or `removeAll`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).