# List in velocity macro, cannot find contains method

Tags: eclipse, velocity

I put a list strings as `validTypes` in velocity. When I do :

```
#if (${validTypes}.contains("aaa"))
  // do something
#end
```

it throws an error. But when I do :

```
#foreach (${validType} in ${validTypes})
   ${validType}
#end
```

it works fine. Do I need to use velocity tools for this? How do I use it in an eclipse plugin?
Are there any work around without using velocity tools?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem here is in curly brackets. Just use

```
#if (${validTypes.contains("aaa")})
```

or

```
#if ($validTypes.contains("aaa"))
```

instead.

Comment: Can you answer this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31116553/how-to-append-hash-tables-in-velocity-template

Answer (score 2):

For those who concern, this is how to write if not,

```
#if (!$validTypes.contains("aaa"))
```